# What's a good troubleshooting path for this? Two RDS instances in 1 security group, 3 clients, and 2 clients cannot connect to one RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Puzzler here:

I have two RDS instances (RDS1 & RDS2) in the same security group (I promise -- I've checked at least ten times).

I have three client machines that have been added to the inbound rules for port 3306 in the security group shared by the RDS instances.

I am testing socket connections to the RDS instances like this:

```
nc -zv my-rds-instance.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
```

Here's the problem:

Client A (workstation): connects to RDS1 but not RDS2

Client B (EC2 in us-west-2c): connects to RDS1 AND to RDS2

Client C (EC2 in us-west-2c): connects to RDS1 but not RDS2

In other words, I need Client A and Client C to connect to RDS2.

The failed connections time-out, so I'm suspecting it's a firewall issue. If I grep netstat -an, I see a SYN_SENT message.

RDS1 is in us-west-2c and RDS2 is in us-west-2b.
They are in the same VPC, the same subnet group, same subnets, and are both publicly accessible on port 3306. RDS1 is MySQL 5.6.27 and RDS2 is 5.5.53.

Client A has MySQL 5.7.17.
Client B has MySQL 5.5.53.
Client C has MySQL 5.5.52.

I'm kind of at my wit's end with how to troubleshoot this further. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the DNS name resolving to the right IP address on all three clients?

Comment: Interesting -- running a dig command on the endpoint from the client that can connect returns the private networking IP, and the public-facing IPs from the other two.

Comment: Using the private IP that resolves from the client that can already connect to the RDS instance, I can connect the other client in the same zone to this.  RDS lists endpoint rather than IPs, is it safe to use the private IP rather than the endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note in a comment, the clients that cannot connect are resolving the DNS name of the RDS box to its public IP. This means that when they attempt to connect, the connection goes out to the big bad Internet, which in turn means the RDS box sees a connection from a fairly arbitrary IP address and (correctly) rejects it.

In the short term, you can "fix" this by using the private IP address of the RDS box, but I don't believe AWS make any long-term guarantees of the stability of those addresses - although they certainly don't change very often. The real fix is of course to fix your DNS do that all the clients are getting the internal IP address of the RDS box; the first place to look there is to check which nameservers each client is using.